# Excel: Conditional formatting formula based on text list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight text in columns `A` - `I` as the information is entered in column `L`.  I tried

```vbs
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$1:$L$5,A1))
```

but it only reflects information entered in `L1`.  I also tried

```vbs
=(COUNT(SEARCH($L$1:$L$5,A1))
```

and this formula highlights everything until there is information in all 5 cells in column L.
[image: excel capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand see if below solution works.

See animated GIF below.

[image]

Use the following conditional Formatting rule. On F3

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(IF(ISBLANK($I$3:$I$7),9^99,$I$3:$I$7),F3),0))>=1
```

Use format painter to apply to all applicable cells below.

Ignore Col G in my example, it was only for testing. In this example search text is in I3:I7, some may be blanks though as relevant.

Note - If I3:I7 is formula based then instead of ISBLANK simply check for ""

something like

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(IF($I$3:$I$7="",9^99,$I$3:$I$7),F3),0))>=1
```

Please confirm if this is how you want it or in case something else.

**Edit 1**

Reason for 9^99 in the formula.

Excel SEARCH returns 1 when you search for blank cell and there could be blanks in the data.
Since this is Text data it's highly unlikely that it will have a very large number like 9^99 (9 to the power of 99)

So to exclude Blanks from SEARCH you replace Blanks with 9^99 which it does not find and returns 0. For all other entries it will return 1 or higher number.

So the inner IF replaces blanks with 9^99. IFERROR returns 0 (Error when 9^99 is not found) all other valid cases return SEARCH outcome being 1 or higher which is used in Conditional Formatting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked perfectly.  Do you mind explaining how 9^99 works in the formula?

Comment: @Tina - See Edit 1 in above answer. Hope you will get an idea how the formula works.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation.  Both greatly appreciated and helpful.

Comment: would it be possible in the conditional formula to also clear the information in the adjacent cells in the row before and after the cell highlighted?  For example, "AMAG" is highlighted in B1 and A1 and C1 changes to 0.